# unexpected token ";;" ocaml

Tags: regex, string, ocaml

This one might be dumb but I just don't see it. This is my code

```
let rec lister old fixed = 
    let paren = Str.regexp "(|)" in 
    match old with
    [] -> []
    | h::t -> if Str.string_match paren h 0 
                 then iter t ((Str.split_delim paren h)@fixed)  
              else  iter t (h::fixed) 
;;

let stl string = 
    let r = Str.regexp " " in 
    let l = lister (Str.split r string) [] 
;;
```

the error is on the last ;; and I'm getting unexpected token ";;". I tried to rework it a bit like

```
let stl string = 
    let l = lister (Str.split (Str.regexp " ") string) [] 
;;
```

but still nothing. I don't think the lister function will have an affect but I've included it anyways. Thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a let-in expression which is incomplete:

```
let stl string = 
    let r = Str.regexp " " in 
    let l = lister (Str.split r s) []
```

Try this:

```
let stl string = 
   let r = Str.regexp " " in 
   lister (Str.split r s) []
```

or you can do something equivalent:

```
let stl string = 
   let r = Str.regexp " " in 
   let l = lister (Str.split r s) [] in
   l
```

Check the [OCaml documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html) for more information.